# java JFreeChart how do I use renderers to set different paints

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a single series XYAreaChart

```
final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYAreaChart(
    "",
    "", "Rolling",
    dataset,
    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
    false,  // legend
    true,  // tool tips
    false  // URLs
);

final XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
```

I want to set paint color to Red when RangeValue >0 otherwise set it to Green. This is the nearest bit of code I can find BUT I think it is for two series:

```
plot.setRenderer(new XYDifferenceRenderer(Color.green, Color.red, false));
```

Which renderer do I need for a single series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be able to help you. Below is an example showing a basic chart from a JFreechart tutorial.  I have added the renderer in your example to it,  my theory is that when you have 1 series the 'second series' as it were is effectively 0.  Therefore when you apply the two series renderer, if the first series dips below 0 it becomes the negative color, and when it is above 0 becomes the positive colour.

When I opened my saved chart it had red on the minus points, and green on the posotive.  See if it helps:

```
public class SO{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create a simple XY chart
    XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Gradient logs chopped");
    series.add(1, -7);
    series.add(2, -2);
    series.add(3, 4);
    series.add(4, 7);
    series.add(5, 10);
    // Add the series to your data set
    XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
    dataset.addSeries(series);
    // Generate the graph
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
    "Logs chopped", // Title
    "Week", // x-axis Label
    "Logs", // y-axis Label
    dataset, // Dataset
    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // Plot Orientation
    true, // Show Legend
    true, // Use tooltips
    false // Configure chart to generate URLs?
    );

    //The renderer part
    XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot(); 
    XYDifferenceRenderer rend = new XYDifferenceRenderer(Color.GREEN, Color.RED, false);
    rend.setSeriesFillPaint(0, Color.DARK_GRAY);
    rend.setRoundXCoordinates(true);
    plot.setRenderer(rend);
    //The renderer part


    try {
    ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(new File("D:\\Users\\user2777005\\Desktop\\XYchart.jpg"), chart, 500, 300);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Problem occurred creating chart.");
    }
   }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: I don't believe that the renderers work in that way - did you find an example anywhere?

Comment: I didn't find any examples, just thought it was worth a go :)

Comment: @ManInMoon The constructor you use for the XYStepRenderer, I can't find it in the documentation, is it some sort of custom creation?

Comment: Sorry, it is this one "Step" exits too but this link is the better one - I will edit question   http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYDifferenceRenderer.html

Comment: @ManInMoon I have re-edited my answer with a slightly altered example, it may be what you are after, you should be able to run it yourself if you want, just add the imports and change the save pathway =D

Comment: @ManInMoon It does work for me,  I am using the latest version (1.0.20 I think) if that makes a difference. The principle should be the same though if you apply the renderer to your chart the way I have applied it to mine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41111/discussion-between-maninmoon-and-user2777005)

Comment: That was it - I needed to update to 1.0.15 - thanks very much